# Gestures flatpak app cannot read configuration file. says "please check permissions"

Tags: permissions, flatpak, gestures

I recently installed the "Gestures" app from flathub and when I launch it, it says "cannot read the configuration file, please check permissions". How can I run this program without this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install all dependencies?
Please refer to this page - https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures/blob/master/README.md

### These steps are from the README

Add yourself to input group

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER input
```

Install dependencies (on Ubuntu/Debian you might need also `libinput-tools`)

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl xdotool
```

Install `libinput-gestures`

```
git clone https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures.git
cd libinput-gestures
sudo make install
```

Default configuration

```
libinput-gestures-setup autostart start
```

This worked for me, but I'm running Fedora, so the case might be different for you.